# How to return only Numbers from a column that has numbers and letters?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Using SQL Server 2005/2008, I am trying to return only the numbers from a column that has some fields with a letter in them as well.

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT Cashregister
FROM
    dbo.RPTrs
WHERE
    TRSDate > GETDATE()-100 AND
    StoreID = @sname
```

Returns

[image]

And this

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT Cashregister
FROM
    dbo.RPTrs
WHERE
    TRSDate > GETDATE()-100 AND
    StoreID = @sname AND
    Cashregister not like '%[^0-9]%'
```

Returns

[image]

What I need is to return all the registers from the first query but without the X in the ones where it is.

Expected Result:

```
   | Cashregister
----------------
1  | 24
2  | 44
3  | 32
4  | 36
5  | 45
6  | 21
7  | 03
8  | 40
9  | 22
10 | 23
11 | 35
12 | 01
13 | 04
14 | 34
15 | 33
16 | 02
```

Comment: Is it always a single leading X and never any other character?

Comment: Yes it is. JW gave the answer though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `REPLACE()`

```
SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(Cashregister, 'X', '') Cashregister
FROM   dbo.RPTrs
WHERE  TRSDate > GETDATE()-100 AND
       StoreID = @sname
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eef69/1)

<strike>Caution: `REPLACE()` is case-sensitive.</strike>

Comment: Well, originally you filtered out using `ISNUMERIC` which was absolutely wrong. Someone else didn't read the question fully before answering either.

Comment: `REPLACE` is not case sensitive except if you happen to be on a CS or BIN collation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use REGEXP if available in your version of SQL. You do not need to use UNION as in my example. This is only to build data w/out table...:

```
-- Digits only --
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('X45','[^0-9]') digits_only FROM your_tab
  UNION
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('X40','[[:digit:]]+') AS digits_only FROM your_tab
/

DIGITS_ONLY
------------
40
45
```

In addition:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('12ZXC3ASD456FGH8TED63','\D') digits_only FROM some_tab
/
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('12ZXC3ASD456FGH8TED63','[^[:digit:]]') digits_only FROM some_tab
/
```

Comment: No, not natively available in any version of SQL Server released to date.